# Get orignal size image using filesGetThumbnail javascript

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

Here is my code

```
  var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' });

function renderItems(items) {
  var filesContainer = document.getElementById('files');
  items.forEach(function(item) {
        dbx.filesGetThumbnail({ path: item.path_display }) // here we need to add size
    .then(function(response) {
            jQuery('#full__gallery__slider').append('<div class="item"><div class="gallery__box"><img src="'+window.URL.createObjectURL(response.fileBlob)+'" class="img-circle"></div></div>');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
  }


dbx.filesListFolder({path: ''})
  .then(function(response) {
     renderItems(response.entries);
});
```

Now I am getting image like 61X57
ISSUE: I just want to know how can i fetch orignal images

Comment: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesGetThumbnail -> https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/global.html#FilesThumbnailArg -> https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/global.html#FilesThumbnailSize

Comment: (If none of those available size options match your requirement … then perhaps you do not want to use a method that has _thumbnail_ in its name to begin with, but rather one to get the original file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the original image data, use [the `filesDownload` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownload__anchor) instead.

The `filesGetThumbnail` is specifically for retrieving resized versions of images, but `filesDownload` can be used to retrieve the original file data for any kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually using the code below to get the sizes of an image

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid');
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

but i am not really sure about the dropbox api.. that i can't guarantee

Comment: It's not relevant about question